# Beautiful Soup find string and then the nth element down

Tags: beautifulsoup

In Beautiful Soup is it possible to search for a text string and then from there find the nth element down?

**Update**
I am Trying to target the following code field to grab the text. I tried a soup find and findall however I have other pages that I want to target that are just slightly different so I need something really robust

**My Plan**

- Go to page
- Find the string Model name
- Find nth element down, in this case the next anchor tag

My code to find string

```
model_name=soup.find(text='Model name')
print model_name
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of HTML you're searching in, the text your searching for and the element you want to find?

Comment: I have update my question with the code.

Comment: You don't actually have a "nth-element down" from that `a` element - it's the only child of its parent. I think you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201929) here.

Comment: By the way, you should paste the actual code (and ideally the URL it comes from), rather than an image of it - no-one's going to waste time typing it in to solve your problem.

Comment: The URL is accessed from an account, not accessible to the public. Its code is a real mess a single block, it is easier to read using the browser debugging tool

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it, its actually really simple. The solution I found gets a little messy but it works

All you got to use is the next operator so the code looks like this

```
model_name=soup.find(text='Model name').next.text
```

adding as many next operators until you reach the target.